How to make TypeScript return a different value depending on an optional argument
I'm writing a fetch() wrapper that takes an options argument. Normally this wrapper will camel case the return value, but if the dontCamelize option is set to true, then it should wrap the return value in a Decamelize<> generic. I'm not sure how to express this in TypeScript though.
Because there could be several options properties, I don't think I can use function overrides. I tried to express it with a ResponseType helper and a conditional type but it doesn't seem to work. Any help is much appreciated!
This code is generated from an OpenAPI spec code generation tool that always passes in the first type parameter, so it will always look like this:
const res = fetcher<{fooBar: 'baz'}>({ fooBar: 'baz' }); // Expect: { fooBar: 'baz' }

TS Playground
type Decamelize<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends string ? `${Uncapitalize<K>}` : K]: T[K]
};

type Options = {
  dontCamelize?: boolean;
  verbose?: boolean;
  // Add more options here as needed
  option1?: string;
  option2?: number;
  option3?: boolean;
};

type ResponseType<T, O extends Options> = 
  O['dontCamelize'] extends true ? Decamelize<T> : T;

export function fetcher<T, O extends Options = {}>(
  subject: T,
  options: O = {} as O
): ResponseType<T, O> {
  return subject as any;
}

// Usage examples
const res1 = fetcher<{ fooBar: 'baz' }>({ fooBar: 'baz' }); // Expect: { fooBar: 'baz' }
const res2 = fetcher<{ fooBar: 'baz' }>({ fooBar: 'baz' }, { dontCamelize: true }); // Expect: Decamelize<{ fooBar: 'baz' }>
const res3 = fetcher<{ fooBar: 'baz' }>({ fooBar: 'baz' }, { verbose: true }); // Expect: { fooBar: 'baz' }
const res4 = fetcher<{ fooBar: 'baz' }>({ fooBar: 'baz' }, { dontCamelize: true, verbose: true }); // Expect: Decamelize<{ fooBar: 'baz' }>


Is dontCamelize the only option that effects the return type?

Remove the explicit type parameter and it works. When you specify one, TS uses the default for the other. If you take them all out, it infers them all, including the options object.

@Darryl Noakes - yes dontCamelize is the only option that changes the response type

@DarrylNoakes I'm not sure which explicit type parameter you're referring to. Do you mind posting an answer?

oh I think you're talking about where I call fetcher<{ fooBar: 'baz' }>(...)
You're right, it does work if I remove that, but unfortunately I need to pass the type in at the call site like that. The actual code that I'm working with is going to pass that type down another level to a util inside of fetcher. It's generated code from an OpenAPI http client and I'm somewhat limited in how it is structured.

Correct. I'll try write up an answer tomorrow, if no one else has answered yet

I don't think this is currently possible without changing the calling code. See Proposal: Partial Type Argument Inference, which is similar to your issue. It does require you to explicitly request inference for the additional parameters. There may be workarounds in there.

Please clarify: (1) Can you modify the call site code or not? (2) Are you writing the fetcher function and calling generated code inside it?

If you're writing it and simply need to pass the type down to a function called inside, inference should be fine. But I don't think that's the case?

Working version using overloads: https://tsplay.dev/NBKZpm

Thank you @DarrylNoakes this looks great!

As long as there is only one* option that affects the return type, you can use function overloads.
* Well, you could have more, but you have to specify an overload for each combination. Two is about the practical max.
(1) Change the Options type to a generic.
The first step is to add a generic type parameter to the options object so we can differentiate between the values of dontCamelize.
Change this:
type Options = {
  dontCamelize?: boolean
}

to this:
type Options<dontCamelize extends boolean = boolean> = {
  dontCamelize?: dontCamelize
}

(2) Change ResponseType to use a boolean type parameter instead of the Options type.
Change this:
type ResponseType<T, O extends Options> = 
  O['dontCamelize'] extends true ? Decamelize<T> : T

to this:
type ResponseType<T, dontCamelize extends boolean> = 
  dontCamelize extends true ? Decamelize<T> : T

(3) Change the function from using a generic type parameter to using overloads.
The overload used depends on the type of dontCamelize in the options object passed in, allowing us to set the return type based on it.
Changes:

Remove the generic type parameter for options.
Add two overloads: one for dontCamelize being false or not specified, and one for it being true.
The return type generic (ResponseType) is passed the corresponding boolean type for dontCamelize.

Change this:
export function fetcher<T, O extends Options = {}>(
  subject: T,
  options: O = {} as O
): ResponseType<T, O>

to this:
// Blank lines added for readability. They're optional.

// Overload signature: `dontCamelize` is not specified or false
export function fetcher<T>(
  subject: T,
  options?: Options<false>
): ResponseType<T, false>

// Overload signature: `dontCamelized` is true
export function fetcher<T>(
  subject: T,
  options: Options<true>
): ResponseType<T, true>

// Implementation signature
export function fetcher<T>(
  subject: T,
  options: Options = {}
): ResponseType<T, boolean>


TS Playground

Remove the explicit generic parameters <{ fooBar: 'baz' }>:
const res1 = fetcher({ fooBar: 'baz' });
const res2 = fetcher({ fooBar: 'baz' }, { dontCamelize: true });
const res3 = fetcher({ fooBar: 'baz' }, { verbose: true });
const res4 = fetcher({ fooBar: 'baz' }, { dontCamelize: true, verbose: true });

TS Playground

As stated in the comments after you posted your answer, and later edited into the question, this approach is not possible.

You don't need to pass it, you can use ResponseType<T, O> inside the fetcher function. And if it is outside the, you don't need it.

The call site has to be of the form const res2 = fetcher<{ fooBar: 'baz' }>({ fooBar: 'baz' }, { dontCamelize: true }), with the explicit type parameter included. This code is not under the OP's control, so it cannot be removed. If the OP has explained correctly.

Not much you can do then. I would try using something like https://ts-morph.com to find function call nodes with namefetcher and remove type parameters from the function call node. I would run this step before your default TSC build step.

Yeah unfortunately the first type parameter has to be passed. The code from the generator produces something like:
httpClient<GetBillsResponse>( { url: /bills, method: 'GET', params },     options   )
I only control the implementation of the httpClient object.
